# How to validate alphabetical order of tableview elements in Xamarin UI tests

Tags: xamarin.ios, automated-tests, xamarin.uitest

I have a list of payee's returned on screen and want to check that they are displayed in alphabetical order. They are displayed in the below format. I want to check that they are ordered by Id: "beneficiary_cell_title_label"

```
[BeneficiaryCellPhone] id: "beneficiary_cell"
[UITableViewCellContentView]
[UILabel] id: "beneficiary_cell_title_label",  label: "Aaa",  text: "Aaa"
[UILabel] id: "beneficiary_cell_number_label",  label: "111",  text: "111"
[UITableTextAccessibilityElement] id: "beneficiary_cell",  label: "Aaa, 111"
[BeneficiaryCellPhone] id: "beneficiary_cell"
[BeneficiaryCellPhone] id: "beneficiary_cell"
[UITableViewCellContentView]
[UILabel] id: "beneficiary_cell_title_label",  label: "Zzz",  text: "Zzz"
[UILabel] id: "beneficiary_cell_number_label",  label: "222",  text: "222"
[UITableTextAccessibilityElement] id: "beneficiary_cell",  label: "Zzz, 222"
[BeneficiaryCellPhone] id: "beneficiary_cell"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved the issue with the following code

```
/// <summary>
        /// Checks the alpha order.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns><c>true</c>, if alpha order was checked, <c>false</c> otherwise.</returns>
        /// <param name="query">Query.</param>
        public bool CheckAlphaOrder(Func<AppQuery,AppQuery> query)
        {
            var list = app.Query(query);
            var orderByAsc = list.OrderBy(d => d.Text);
            if (list.SequenceEqual(orderByAsc))
            {
                return true;
            }else{
                return false;
            }
        }
```